# How to get constant water pressure in a circular distribution pipe?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water, flow

I have a circular 3/4" pipe( 62" in diameter). It has 11 tee outlets, 3/4"x3/4" to 1/2", which each have a 1/2" hose that funnels the water downward.

The pump(400gph) is pumping the water vertically up through a 1/2" pipe into a 3/4" x 3/4" x 1/2" tee. This tee spilts the water two ways into the circular pipe.

My problem is that when the water reaches the hose they are filling up equally, but the first hose that fills up is the only one that continues having water flow. While the rest remain dry. How do I keep the water pressure constant so it runs equally through all the hoses?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the water flow is consistent in all 11 outlets without the hoses attached (which is no easy task), then it sounds like you are getting some siphoning action on the first hose that fills. One solution is to introduce an air inlet device at the high point of each hose. Another solution would be to point the barbed fittings downward and make sure that each hose is cut to identical length.